# WebSphere MQ Cluster QMGR, Mechanism of dispatch messages to nodes

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using WAS MQ 7.0 and there is my scenario;

I have a Cluster Queue Manager which name `'CLUSD'` and two nodes for clustering which names `'N1' , 'N2'`.

N1 and N2 configurations are as the same which means there is no priority set for each queue.

When I tried to send messages to `CLUSD`, the QMGR tried to send messages to their nodes (`N1, N2`); but there is no undestandable mechanism that why sometimes `N1` is get more messages than N2 and vise versa.

I have a message producer which send messages in a while loop for couple of minutes. After each minute I get count of enqueue for each nodes queue; obviously always there is different between count of `N1` and `N2`.

I know when I tried to use WAS MQ, always I have bigger fish to fry ;) but I want to get same result when there is same configuration such as software, hardware and etc.

What can I do for cover this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented here http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzah.doc/qc10940_.htm:

The distribution of user messages is not always exact, because administration and maintenance of the cluster causes messages to flow across channels. The result is an uneven distribution of user messages which can take some time to stabilize. Because of the admixture of administration and user messages, place no reliance on the exact distribution of messages during workload balancing.

This blog describes more:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/websphere_mq_clustering_workload_balancing_dick_hamilton14?lang=en